# Is reasonable to assume that the 食 in 月食/日食 can be interpreted as the sun/moon being "eaten" during an eclipse?

Tags: kanji, etymology

So I'm quite new to Japanese, and I'm having a blast being able to understand some basic compound words based on individual kanji, and in some cases the process is quite straightforward. However, I don't want to get carried away because I understand that of course kanji can have, in some cases, many readings, so I could sometimes end up with complete nonsense.

That being said, in the particular case of my question, is it reasonable to assume that the 食 in 月食/日食 can be interpreted as the moon/sun being "eaten" during an eclipse or is there another reason to use this kanji? I have read that a different kanji was used before (at least for lunar eclipse, 月蝕), but I haven't been able to find an explanation about the etymology itself or to verify that it is indeed as simple as it looks.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: I don't know if you've ever read it, but in the manga Toriko there's a fairy tale about a グルメ日食 which is supposedly an event where a colossal demon awakens and devours the sun.

Comment: Didn't know of it, I looked it up now, that's an interesting observation, thanks !

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Rather than interpreting「食」as its original meaning *eaten*, it is probably more accurate to interpret it for its secondary meaning that developed in Old Chinese: *wear away, corrode, damage [something]*. This is the same kind of semantic extension as English (e.g. *acid **eats away** at metal > corrosion*). Thus, eclipses are a *wearing away* of the sun or moon.

Apart from eclipses,「食」was very early on used to describe similar phenomenon, such as the transition from a full moon to a new moon. From the [*Book of Changes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Ching):

> 《[易經](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Ching)・豐卦・彖曰》：「日中則昃，月盈則食」
>
> *When the sun reaches the [meridian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meridian_(astronomy))* [i.e. noon]*, it thus travels west* [i.e. sets]*. When the moon becomes full, it thus fades away*.

The *wear away, corrode* sense is now written as「蝕」, so「食」is the original and older form of the character used in the meaning *eclipse*.

---

> In contrast to the later-formed character [「蝕」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=3655), *eclipses* were known as「食」since the [Shang dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty). Eclipses were often interpreted as omens of some sort, and whether or not they were auspicious were corroborated by [oracle bone divinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone). From [《甲骨文合集》33694](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=33694&jgwfl=), read from the bottom sentence then the top sentence:
>
> > 癸酉貞：日月又（有）食，隹（唯）若？
> >
> > *Divination on* [癸酉](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%99%B8%E9%85%89) *day, it is asked: If the sun or moon is eclipsed, is this an auspicious sign?*
> >
> > 癸酉貞：日月又（有）食，⿱非若？
> >
> > *Divination on* 癸酉 *day, it is asked: If the sun or moon is eclipsed, is this **not** an auspicious sign?*
>
> [image]

Comment: I see, that is a great explanation, especially for the different kanji usage.
Thank you very much !